# How to enlist with a TransactionScope?

Tags: .net, transactionscope

### Short Version

How do i enlist in an ongoing **TransactionScope**?

### Long Version

If you use a **TransactionScope**, you can create an *"ambient"* transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   //...stuff happens, then you complete...

   // The Complete method commits the transaction. 
   scope.Complete();
}
```

What is that good for? Well, there are some classes in the .NET framework that know how to check if there is an ambient ongoing transaction by checking the `static`:

- [**System.Transactions.Current**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.current?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Transactions_Transaction_Current)

This lets them know that there is a transaction in progress.

For example, if you had some arbitrary database operation that otherwise didn't consider transactions:

```
void DropStudents()
{
   using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE Students;";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

If you plop that in the middle of a **TransactionScope**:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   DropStudents();

   // The Complete method commits the transaction. 
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Suddnely your ADO.net operations are in a transaction; and can be rolled back.

### Automatic BeginTranasction, Commit, and Rollback

The **SqlClient** library knows to check:

- **System.Transactions.Current**

and automatically internally:

- Begin a database transaction
- Commit the database transaction when you call **Scope.Complete**
- Rollback the database transaction when the scope is rolled back

And it's all just magic.

- somehow the `DbConnection` gets a notification to call `.Commit`
- and somehow the `DbConnection` gets a notification to call `.Rollback`

### How do i do that?

I have a class that also has transactions. And rather than forcing the caller to call:

```
using (IContosoTransaction tx = turboEncabulator.BeginTransaction())
{
   try
   {
      turboEncabulator.UpendCardinalGrammeters();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      tx.Rollback();
      throw;
   }
   tx.Commit();
}
```

It would be nice if they could just call:

```
turboEncabulator.UpendCardinalGrammeters();
```

And my code will simply check:

- **System.Transactions.Current**

And if there is a transaction in progress, i will:

- begin a transaction
- wait for the notification to **Commit**
- or wait for the notification to **Rollback**

But how do i do that?

How do i register myself with an ongoing **TransactionScope** to get these notifications?

Comment: `Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => ...`?

Comment: @GuruStron `Transaction.Current.TransactionRolledBack?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that bad actually.

1. Check if there is a transaction in progress by seeing if `System.Transactions.Transaction.Current` is assigned. If there is, `Enlist` in the transaction:

   ```
   //Enlist in any current transactionScope if one is active
   if (System.Transactions.Transaction.Current != null)
      System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(this, EnlistmentOptions.None);
   ```

   I pass `this`, as the object that will get the notification callbacks through the `IEnlistmentNotification` interface that it must implement.
2. And then you need to implement the four notification methods of [`IEnlistmentNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification?view=net-5.0):

   - `void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment);`
   - `void Commit(Enlistment enlistment);`
   - `void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment);`
   - `void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment);`

The actual implementations are trivial boilerplate notifications:

- **Prepare**: Transaction manager is asking for your vote on whether the transaction is good to be committed:

  - To vote <kbd>Yes</kbd>: call `preparingEnlistment.Prepared();`
  - To vote <kbd>No</kbd>: call `preparingEnlistment.ForceRollback();`
- **Commit**: Do your stuff to commit and declare that you are done with your enlistment:

  - `enlistment.Done();`
- **InDoubt**: Notification that the transaction manager lost communication with someone else involved in the transaction. Respond by letting them know you are done with the enlistment:

  - `enlistment.Done();`
- **Rollback**: Notification that the transaction is being rolled back. Do any sort of rollback work, and let them know you're done with the enlistment:

  - `enlistment.Done();`

### Or more fully

```
public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
{
   //The transaction manager is asking for our vote if the transaction
   //can be committed

   //Vote "yes" by calling .Prepared:
   preparingenlistment.Prepared();

   //Vote "no" by calling .ForceRollback:
   //preparingEnlistment.ForceRollback();
}

public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
{
   //The transaction is being committed - do whatever it is we do to commit.

   //Let them know we're done with the enlistment.
   enlistment.Done();
}

public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
{
   //Do any work necessary when indoubt notification is received.
   //This method is called if the transaction manager loses contact with one or more participants, 
   //so their status is unknown.
   //If this occurs, you should log this fact so that you can investigate later whether any of the 
   //transaction participants has been left in an inconsistent state.

   //Let them know we're done with the enlistment.
   enlistment.Done();
}

public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
{
   //If any resource manager reported a failure to prepare in phase 1, the transaction manager invokes 
   //the Rollback method for each resource manager and indicates to the application the failure of the commit.

   //Let them know we're done with the enlistment.
   enlistment.Done();
}
```

Comment: This is great and provides what I think is the "real" answer that people who asked these questions were actually looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417857/how-does-transactionscope-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494550/how-does-transactionscope-roll-back-transactions